# Lambda capture: to use the initializer or not to use it?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Consider the following, minimal example:

```
int main() {
    int x = 10;    
    auto f1 = [x](){ };
    auto f2 = [x = x](){};
}
```

I've seen more than once such an use of the initializer `[x = x]`, but I can't fully understand it and why I should use it instead of `[x]`.
I can get the meaning of something like `[&x = x]` or `[x = x + 1]` (as shown in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and why they differ from `[x]`, of course, but still I can't figure out the differences between the lambdas in the example.

Are they fully interchangeable or is there any difference I can't see?

Comment: It matters if the original `x` is `const`.

Comment: Does it capture it by copy in both cases?

Comment: @skypjack : In the `[x = ...]` case, `x` can be copy or move-initialized – it depends on the right-hand-side expression. For `[x = x]` specifically, that is copy-initialization, yes.

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah, I understand what happens in `[x = ...]`, that's the case `[x = x]` that does not make much sense to me, even though I've seen it used around.

Comment: @skypjack : As @T.C. said, `[x = x]` drops const/volatile off the outer `x`'s type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are various corner cases that pretty much boils down to "`[x = x]` decays; `[x]` doesn't".

- capturing a reference to function:

  ```
  void (&f)() = /* ...*/;
  [f]{};     // the lambda stores a reference to function.
  [f = f]{}; // the lambda stores a function pointer
  ```
- capturing an array:

  ```
  int a[2]={};
  [a]{}     // the lambda stores an array of two ints, copied from 'a'
  [a = a]{} // the lambda stores an int*
  ```
- capturing a cv-qualified thing:

  ```
  const int i = 0; 
  [i]() mutable { i = 1; } // error; the data member is of type const int
  [i = i]() mutable { i = 1; } // OK; the data member's type is int
  ```

Comment: So, it's as you said in the comment - *It matters if the original `x` is `const`*. The other cases don't seem to be of interest indeed. Thank you.