# Is lambda with initializer to itself equivalent to lambda without initializer?

Tags: c++, lambda, shared-ptr

Are the following two code snippets identical, regardless of the type and qualifiers of `response`, assuming that the copy constructor and copy assignment operator have no side-effects?

```
auto foo = [response]() {
    do_something(response);
};
```

And

```
auto foo = [response = response]() {
    do_something(response);
};
```

It would seem that they do exactly the same thing – **copy** the object response – but in certain cases, only the second version compiles.

Here is a sample program to demonstrate the issue:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
void do_something() {
}
int main() {
    auto au = [](auto callback) {
        callback();
    };
    auto x = [&au](shared_ptr<int> response) {
        au([response = move(response)]() mutable {
            auto foo = [response/* = response*/]() { // uncomment and it will work
                do_something();
            };
        });
    };
    x(make_shared<int>(100));
}
```

It seems that `response` must be a `std::shared_ptr` for this issue to happen, but I'm not sure why.  I understand that copying a `shared_ptr` does not copy the actual resource (i.e. the `int`), but I fail to see how it might cause the code to fail to compile.  I have always believed that the top two code snippets do exactly the same thing.

If it's needed, I use MSVC 2015 and compiled it with Debug x86, but I think compiling it as Release or as x64 gives the same result.

Comment: The commented version works for me on both gcc and clang. This might be a compiler bug.

Comment: [There are cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36188986/3953764) where the syntax used for capturing a variable matters, none of them seems to apply to your code

Comment: There's a difference in how the name lookup works for those two forms, not sure if that's causing the problem with MSVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the compiler. The latest VisualC++ `v19.10.24903.0` will compile it. You can try it online [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).

Comment: It would seem to be so.  I just tested it online [here](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) and the issue exists there too.

Comment: @Bernard exactly :)